# p:autoComplete does not work with single char

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I have a page with two inputtext (I'll name them "name" and "id"): one that compares the text entered with a string and another one that compares it with an int converted to string. 
Now the problem is this: if I have an "id" == 1 and type 1 into the inputtext, the autocomplete shows only results with two or more digits/chars (so 11,31,117 etc but not 1)...
This is the html:

```
<p:autoComplete id="CustomerId" value="#{myBean.CustomerBean.id}"
    completeMethod="#{myBean.autoCompleteId}"
    maxResults="10">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{myBean.selectCustomerById}"
        update="resultMessage name idComp table newAssociation" />
</p:autoComplete>
```

And this is the autocomplete method:

```
    public List<String> autoCompleteId(String query) {
     CustomerList = myService.selectByFilters(CustomerBean);
     setAcList(new ArrayList<String>());
     for (int i = 0; i < CustomerList.size(); i++) {
        CustomerAnag tip = CustomerList .get(i);
        if(String.valueOf(tip.getId()).contains(query) || String.valueOf(tip.getId()).equals(query)) {
            acList.add(tip.getId().toString());
        } 
     }
     return acList;
   }
```

What in the sweet heaven am I doing wrong ?!

Comment: You're sure CustimerList has an CustomerAnag with Id==1?
Or id==1 is not in the first 10(maxResults) position in your list.

Comment: absolutely. I'm starting to think this is a bug since even in the primefaces' page you can see it won't suggest anything with number of chars < 2.......

Comment: try this...
`...
for (int i = 0; i < CustomerList.size(); i++) {
        CustomerAnag tip = CustomerList .get(i);
        if(String.valueOf(tip.getId()).equals(query))
        {
                    acList.add(tip.getId().toString());
                    return acList;
        }    
        if(String.valueOf(tip.getId()).contains(query)
            acList.add(tip.getId().toString());
        } 
     }
return acList;
`
if this wont chance anything, you could be right "it won't suggest anything with number of chars < 2"

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but this way it's either one char OR more than one... there won't be a list of suggestions with everything in it. BTW I'm trying right now

Comment: On the other handside why do you need this "autoComplete" for id==1 if there is nothing to "autoComplete"?

Comment: `I'm starting to think this is a bug since even in the primefaces' page you can see it won't suggest anything with number of chars < 2` - because the showcase just returns (query + i) for i from 0 to 9 as results, no bug here.